# ID List range copying

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the below script which I have cobbled together from various sources on here.  It is meant to take a list from column B in a spreadsheet full of Google File Id's and then access those files and copy a range of data in each of the 4 sheets in the individual files and place in a master sheet.

The individual components work but once I input my specific names and merge them I have and error:

> Missing ) after argument list. (line 14, file "ID List loop and copy")

Line 14 is the last line with the `}}}}` in it!
spreadsheet with Ids is "listing of folder ZZ Daily Schedules Archived" and spreadsheet for range to be copied to is "Archives"  Just in case I missed something.

```
function getDataToMaster2() {
   var sheetIds = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("listing 
   of folder ZZ Daily Schedules Archived");
   var values = sheetIds.getRange('B:B').getValues();
   var idList = values.map(function (row) { return row[0]; }).filter(function 
   (id) { return id; });
    // Loop through and open Spreadsheet files by `id`
    for (var i = 0; i < idList.length; i++) {  
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idList[i]).getSheets();

    // Perform an action on each sheet within the open Spreadsheet
    sheets.forEach(function (e) {
    var data = e.getRange('A7:U38').getValues();
    var sn = ['AM trip','PM trip','Pool / Beach','Night Dive']
    getSheetByName (sn[innerLoopIndex])
    Logger.log("sheet name: %s", e.getSheetName());


    });
    }}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `filter()` was not closed

```
function getDataToMaster2() {
  var sheetIds = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("listing of folder ZZ Daily Schedules Archived");
  var values = sheetIds.getRange('B:B').getValues();
  var idList = values.map(function (row) { return row[0]; }).filter(function (id) { return id; });
  // Loop through and open Spreadsheet files by `id`
  for (var i = 0; i < idList.length; i++) {  
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idList[i]).getSheets();

    // Perform an action on each sheet within the open Spreadsheet
    sheets.forEach(function (e) {
      var data = e.getRange('A7:U38').getValues();
      Logger.log("sheet name: %s", e.getSheetName());

      // sheetMaster.insertRowsAfter(lastRow, data.length);
      // sheetMaster.getRange(lastRow + 1, 2, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
    });
  }
}
```

Also, [getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String)) will return `null` unless the full single sheet name is actually: 
`'AM trip','PM trip','Pool / Beach','Night Dive'`

Comment: If i made it getSheetByNames() would that iterate through all 4 sheets and copy to same sheet names in archive worksheet?  Thank you for catching the open filter!  Duh.

Comment: There is not a `getSheetByNames()` available. Updated the above code to loop through **each** sheet in the open Spreadsheet. If you only want to open the sheets with those specific names - then instead of the `forEach()` replace it with an inner `for` loop that loops through an array of sheetname `var sn = ['AM trip','PM trip','Pool / Beach','Night Dive']`  and use `getSheetByName (sn[innerLoopIndex])` to get each named sheet

Comment: I have updated the question script with your input.  Thank you very much.  Can you see I entered your last section correctly, thanks.  I do have 4 sheets I want to copy but 6 sheets in each worksheet, you were AGAIN correct.